# draw.io - adding row only?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Adding row to table using the table control is utterly frustrating. Only a cell is added to the table. Has anyone solved this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug, we're tracking it at https://trello.com/c/7khNPau7/344-problems-inserting-new-row-in-table

Answer (score 1):

Just tried and the row control seems buggy - anyhow if you double-click in the last cell, this control should be displayed somewhere:

> [image]

Clicking the down arrow adds a new row.

I've tried to create an animated gif:
[image]

As you can see, the controls are not displayed where they should and the images in the table are messy, but at least you get a full new row...

Comment: Interesting. I have tried both using draw io in the browser (chrome) and the desktop version but I cannot get the control to display no matter how much or where i press.

Comment: @geogrow I did it with firefox but didn't get the controls with chromium. Seems like a really buggy feature to me...

Answer (score 0):

Reposting this from a different page because this questions is asked about five times...

---

This was remarkably frustrating because the "Format Panel" that displays the table options doesn't pop up unless it's been previously activated:

To access the "Format Panel": create a table, click on the table, then...

- Opt1: click the Grid icon (its directly under the draw.io icon) and select "Format Panel"
- Opt2: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>